# Gradle > Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug FAILED

Tags: android, gradle

I have a kotlin project and i used Navigation component.
in my local machine i can use `gradle build` and it's work ok.
but in my remote ubuntu when i call `gradle build` i get this message
can anyone help me

> root@sarvdata:/home/test2/WooShop# gradle build
>   Task :app:generateSafeArgsDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:generateSafeArgsDebug'.

  > org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

[image: gradle build]

Comment: Same situation, kotlin + navigation but my problem is on my local machine

Comment: can you try with ./gradle build ?

Comment: try with `gradle --stacktrace build` or `gradle --debug build` and post the output for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this problem in Android Project with Navigation component and I have navigation dir with empty navigation xml file just remove navigation dir and rebuild then I can build.

Answer (score 24):

Got the same error. Did a search with `grep -r "\x00"  app/src/main/res` and a app/src/main/res/navigation/.DS_Store file came up. Deleted it and everything played out.

Comment: This seems to be the solution on MacOS!

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my time!

Comment: Holy s**t, half a day of trying everything, cleaning all gradle caches and nuking Android Studio. And this was the solution...
Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, after proper checking, I realized there was an error in my navigation graph's code. The error was gone after correctly formatting and correcting the error. I suggest you check your navigation graph's code for any misspellings or errors and if you are not using navigation then delete the graph entirely. The error is shown below.

**WRONG:**

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.opeyemiabdulsalam.carowners.CarOwnersFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/car_owners_list">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="filterValue"
            app:argType="com.example.opeyemiabdulsalam.data.Filter"
            <!--            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"-->
            pop
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
        </fragment>
```

**RIGHT:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
    android:name="com.example.opeyemiabdulsalam.carowners.CarOwnersFragment"
    android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
    tools:layout="@layout/car_owners_list">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="filterValue"
        app:argType="com.example.opeyemiabdulsalam.data.Filter"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Trying to find xml file with this character but I think its generated by Safe Args gradle plugin. Solved problem by creating empty Android project and copied existing code and resources into this.

Comment: I solved it by deleting the project and downloading it again from vc, but i still wouldnt consider that as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

something starting with `\u0` seems the be escaped Unicode ...so this might be an encoding issue. searching XML files for string `\u0` should locate the problematic file and shed some light on the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the additional message:

```
simplenames must not contain empty items: []
```

Came out that I forgot to add some value to `app:argType=""` inside my `nav_graph_xml_file`

Check your Navigation Graph file like @Abdulsalam Opeyemi mentioned above.